# Using word "clip" to refer to a short video

Tags: word-usage

For some reason Russians often insist on using English word "clip" to refer to a "short video", especially a "music video" on TV. I know that what Russians would call a "clip" is actually called "music video" by English native speakers. And I know that to "clip" is a verb rather than a noun. Does anybody use word "clip" to refer to some video or piece of video in English?

My Russian colleagues try to convince me that we should call videos "clips" on our site because that's how people would search them on Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clip is also a noun and used to describe short pieces of video by native English speakers.  However, they would probably not use it to describe a music video or "a short video" (that is, a complete video which is intended to be short).  A key connotation of "clip" in this sense is that it as an incomplete excerpt from a larger work.  For example, "to illustrate the problems, the movie reviewers played a few clips of the movie they were discussing".

Comment: _Clip_, in the sense of a short sequence of moving images, comes from the days of celluloid film. A brief scene from a feature film, perhaps shown in a trailer, was seen as having been clipped (cut) out of the main film reel.